# Local Cosmos DB service unavailable

Tags: windows, azure, document-oriented, cosmos-db

I've installed the azure cosmos db in my local machine but is not loading the explorer pages as shown below:

[image]

**Explicit error**:

Failed to get authorization headers for offers: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"code\":\"ServiceUnavailable\",\"message\":\"Service is currently unavailable.\r\nActivityId: d728958b-c0b4-4b32-a131-bba1dc7a8ba0, \r\nResponseTime: 2018-06-05T17:22:33.8740685Z, StoreReadResult:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue usually happens when we have Pulse Secure installed, I have uninstalled Pulse Secure as it was no longer needed and that fixed the problem.

Related Post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569917/documentdb-emulator-not-working-service-unavailable?rq=1